# How do I re-name the headers of my Fasta file?

Tags: fasta, text-processing

I appologize for asking this, but I really am really bad with regex...

Can someone help me transform the headers of my fasta files from this:

```
>Agaricus_chiangmaiensis|JF514531|SH174817.07FU|reps|k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Agaricomycetes;o__Agaricales;f__Agaricaceae;g__Agaricus;s__Agaricus_chiangmaiensis
```

to this:

```
>JF514531|SH174817.07FU;tax=d:Fungi,p:Basidiomycota,c:Agaricomycetes,o:Agaricales,f:Agaricaceae,g:Agaricus,s:Agaricus_chiangmaiensis_SH174817.07FU;
```

seems like I could use the command

```
sed 's/__/:/g;s/;/,/g;s/.*|/|/g'
```

to substitute `:` for `__`, and `,` for `;`.  I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from there though...

Thank you

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and explain the transformation you need please? You don't only want to replace `__` with `:` and `;` with `,`. You also seem to be removing some text. Do you always want to remove whatever is before the first `|`? And what happened to the `reps`? And why is `k__Fungi` becoming `tax=d:Fungi` instead of `k:Fungi`? We need to know exactly what you are trying to do in order to give an answer that works for you.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out without more clarification - I'll try to be more concise when asking in the future -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `awk` is good as well:

```
$ awk -v FS="|" -v OFS="|" '/>/{
    gsub(";",",", $5); 
    gsub("__",":",$5); 
    print ">"$2,$3";tax="$5"_"$3";";
    next;
}1' file.fa
>JF514531|SH174817.07FU;tax=k:Fungi,p:Basidiomycota,c:Agaricomycetes,o:Agaricales,f:Agaricaceae,g:Agaricus,s:Agaricus_chiangmaiensis_SH174817.07FU;
```

This relies on the order of the parts separated by `|`.

I don't understand why `k__Fungi` becomes `d:Fungi`, so I ignored it for now.

Some explanation for what `awk`is doing.

- `|` is defined as a field (column) separator for the input and output
- If the line contains a `>` the code between `{` and `}` is executed.
- the first `gsub` replaces `;` with `,` in the 5th field
- the second `gsub` replaces `__` with `:` in the 5th field
- then we print the new header line. The `$2`, `$3` and `$5` get replaced by the values of the second, third and 5th field of the input. `,` get replaced by the defined output field separator
- with `next` we tell `awk` to go to the next input line and repeat the code
- The `1` is in equivalent to `print $0` for printing the whole input line. In our code this is only executed if the line is no header line.

Comment: I don't know awk that well. However, I find this is a really nice example and it makes me want to learn more awk!

Comment: Note that this won't print the sequences, only the header.

Comment: I just noticed this - how would you change this?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to do four things:

1. Remove all text up to and including the first `|`.
2. Now that that has been removed, take the string between what is now (after step 1) the first `|` and what is now the second `|`, and append it to the end of the header with a `_`.
3. Replace all `__` with `:` and all `;` with `,`.
4. Change the (fixed?) string `reps|k` with `tax=d`.

If so, and assuming that you only have one occurrence of `reps|` in each header, you can do:

```
$ sed 's/>[^|]*|/>/; 
       s/reps|k/tax=d/; 
       s/__/:/g; 
       s/;/,/g; 
       s/|\([^|]*\)\(|.*\)/|\1\2_\1;/; ' file.fa 
>JF514531|SH174817.07FU;tax=d:Fungi,p:Basidiomycota,c:Agaricomycetes,o:Agaricales,f:Agaricaceae,g:Agaricus,s:Agaricus_chiangmaiensis_SH174817.07FU;
```

This will:

- `s/>[^|]*|/>/` : replace the longest stretch of non`-|` characters after a `>` and until the first `|` with `>` alone.
- `s/reps|k/tax=d/;` : replace the first occurrence of the string `reps|k` with `tax=`.
- `s/__/:/g; s/;/,/g` : replace *all* (that's what the `/g` means) occurrences of `__` with `:` and of `;` with `,`.
- `s/|\([^|]*\)\(|.*\)/|\1\2_\1;/` : the `\(foo\)` construct is called a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and will *capture* `foo` and save it as `\1`, which can be used on the right hand side of the replacement operator. The next captured group will be `\2` then `\3` etc. Here, with `|\([^|]*\)` we are capturing the longest string of non`|` found after the 1st `|` (this happens after the first operation, so the 1st `|` is the one that was 3rd in the original) and then everything after the next `|` (`|.*`) until the end of the line. We then replace everything matched with a `|`, then whatever was matched by the first capture group (`\1`), then the second (`\2`), then we add a `_` and repeat the `\1`. 
  Finally, if you want to make the changes to the original input file, use `-i`:

  ```
  sed -i.bak 's/>[^|]*|/>/; s/reps|k/tax=d/; s/__/:/g; s/;/,/g; s/|\([^|]*\)\(|.*\)/|\1\2_\1;/; ' file.fa
  ```

  That will save the original file as `file.fa.bak`. use `-i` alone without any argument if you don't need the backup.

Comment: This works really well, except for two things:  the command changes reps to tax for every other header, and there is still a | in front of tax instead of ;.